# MySQL error 1148 on LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with local-infile=1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an import process which takes a tab-separated values file and cleans it into another tab-separated values file ready for use with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`.

When I run this process on my testing batch process server it works fine, connecting to the MySQL server running on another VM and completing the import process successfully.

When I run it on my staging batch process server, I get the following exception from PDO:

```
PDOException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not
                 allowed with this MySQL version
```

I gather this error is usually caused by a missing `local-infile=1` option, either on the client or in the server's configuration, however this appears to be being set in all the correct places as the process works on the testing server, yet I am still receiving this error on staging.

I am creating my PDO connection as follows:

```
$db = new \PDO("mysql:host={$connParams['host']};dbname={$connParams['dbname']}",
        $connParams['user'], $connParams['password'], [
    \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true,
]);
```

And the `LOAD DATA` statement is created and executed as follows: *

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE :file INTO TABLE `fll_import_data`
                      FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'\t\';');
$stmt->bindParam(':file', $userDataFile, \PDO::PARAM_STR, strlen($userDataFile));
$stmt->execute();
```

On the MySQL server, `local_infile` is set to `ON`:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%local%';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`mysqld` was not started with `--local-infile=0` in its command line:

```
$ ps aux | grep [m]ysql
mysql    11976  0.0  0.0   4180   728 ?        S    13:32   0:00
    /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    12537  0.0  0.8 532896 132580 ?       Sl   13:32   0:01
    /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysql/error.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
$
```

I have the following in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf` on both servers:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
local-infile=1

[mysqld]
innodb_large_prefix=ON
innodb_file_format=BARRACUDA
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
innodb_strict_mode=ON
innodb_file_per_table=ON
default_time_zone='+00:00'
local-infile=1

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
local-infile=1
```

`open_basedir` is empty on both servers. (`var_dump`ing it yields `string(0) ""`)

`mysqld` is version `5.6.23-1~dotdeb.3` on both servers, and `php` is version `5.5.23-1~dotdeb.2`, again on both servers.

I'm stumped, as the process works perfectly on the testing environment. There has to be a configuration option I'm missing somewhere along the line on the staging servers, either in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` or `/etc/mysql/*`, but all of the other SO posts regarding this issue point to the lack of local-infile=1 in the configuration or the missing `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` parameter when instantiating PDO, but I definitely have both of those in place.

Anyone got any ideas?

(* **Note:** PDO allows prepared LOAD DATA statements as it emulates the preparation process)

---

**Update 1**

Just to confirm, I can successfully run `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` from the MySQL command line client:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/batch-user/test.dat' INTO TABLE `test` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 8 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 8

mysql>
```

Comment: What are the exact differences between the testing batch process server and staging batch process server? Are you using php-MySQL or php--mysqlnd ?

Comment: Aha, that one could do it. Y'know, I hadn't even thought to check that! I suspect that the testing server has `php5-mysqlnd` installed and the staging one has `php5-mysql`, or vice versa. I'll have to check on Tuesday now, as I can't log in to the servers remotely.

Comment: TwoWholeWorms, it took me well over a day to fix that